# Storing API keys in UWP

Tags: security, configuration, uwp, azure-devops

From what I can understand there is no config-file system like ConfigurationManager in UWP. My question is therefore, where to I put API-keys that need to differ between environments? I also want to be able to switch the environment after build, so keeping the keys in the code (with compile flags) is not an option. Is there a best-practice way of doing this?

Comment: What constitutes an *"environment"*, and how do you *"switch the environment"*? Why is keeping the keys in code not an option? Are those keys regarded sensitive information?

Comment: By environment I mean dev, qa/test or production. I would like to use the same build in all environments but switch the keys before deploying to a specific environment (like with config files). The repo is private so I guess putting the keys in the code is ok from a security perspective, but thats not possible if the same build should be used for all environments. I use Azure DevOps for builds and deployments. I welcome any suggestions on how to this is done the most correct way.

Comment: If you want something *"like [a] config file"*, why not use a config file?

Comment: I gueesed ConfigurationManager does not work in UWP for a reason, thats way I asked for "the correct way" to do it.

Comment: Just because you plan to *manage* *configurations* doesn't mean that you have to use a type whose name contains *"manage"* and *"configuration"*. You can use *any* strategy that solves your issue, like adding a JSON file to your package, and accessing it through the `ms-appx:` [URI scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/uri-schemes). *"The correct way"* depends on answers to questions I asked for in a previous comment.

Comment: Yes I understand that. I know how to store and load files in UWP. I simply wonder how others are solving this. Also, why is ConfigurationMangager not around any more? Just looking for insights regarding this. Maybe others have put effort in to analyze different approaches? A little discussion can be enlightening! So, please tell me, is there no problems associated with using a config file? Are there no security pitfalls?

Answer (score 0):

[App settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/app-settings/app-settings-and-data) provides an easy to use programming interface - a `key-value` pairs to store/retrieve data - which is similar to `ConfigurationManager`.

```
var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;

localSettings.Values["APIKey_SIT"] = "Hello World";
```

Unlike `ConfigurationManager` which reads/writes plain `XML` configuration, app settings is a `Settings.dat` file sits in the `Settings` folder of the app data, and is accessible to the app alone.

[image]

Comment: The problem is that you have to add these settings at runtime and I think OP needs to have them beforehand

Comment: I thought of this, good point. But really a `conundrum`, to be able to have configurable values beforehand, an additional file (json/xml or whatever) is inevitable.

Comment: I just read your now-deleted answer, I think your appoach is workable, if the file is in the app package (the inaccessible `WindowsApp` folder), the file should be safe from malicious code. Could not get a chance to read your comments though.

Comment: Yes, @IInspectable mentioned it is better to encrypt the file as well, which is of course true, but attacker can access it anyway, which is what I was trying to say in the comments, but was not understood so I thought it will be better to delete my answer and make space for a better answer.

Comment: @mar: You were well understood in repeatedly claiming, that **in a compromised system** there is no security. While undoubtedly true, that doesn't help much. I outlined how privacy is implemented in the `PasswordVault`, and explained, that it doesn't provide *any* additional security over storing a password in plain-text, in an application-private location, when run on a compromised system. That all sounds like a fundamental misunderstanding on your part of how security is established.

Comment: Okay, can we let it go when I proclaim that I fundamentally don't understand security :-D ? But please write an answer which describes how to store the credentials securely.

Comment: @mar: Since I haven't gotten a response to my request for clarification, it's unlikely for me to provide any guidance. Posting answers based on guessing - even if educated - isn't helpful. It's entirely unclear to me, why you get all worked up when receiving factually correct, **verifiable** information, that proves you wrong. If you believe to be right, you certainly have something more sustainable to offer to explain yourself on a technical level.

Comment: I am not saying you are wrong or anything like that. The additional layer of security by encrypting the file is undoubtedly worth it and I admit I should have mentioned that in the answer and I didn't, so I was wrong there. And fact is that `PasswordVault` is recommended by Microsoft as the way to store user credentials for UWP apps, which is why I mentioned it, nothing less, nothing more. I don't want to argue with anyone and I don't see the reason why do you think I do.